# List of theories supporting origin of universe

Tags: universe, big-bang

Big Bang theory is widely accepted theory when it comes to origin of universe. What other really compelling theories are out there explaining/supporting the origin of universe. I know many people don't believe in Big Bang theory for various reasons.

**Update**
Question was not complete before for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cyclic theories (Steinhardt, Turok), Big Bounce theories (LQG), eternal inflation (Linde etc, variant of the Big Bang), Conformal Cyclic Cosmology (Penrose, variant of the Big Bang), "No Boundary" origin (Hawking, Hartle, variant of Big Bang with no singularity and imaginary time), the self-creating universe ([Richard Gott](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9712344) )-unlikely but fun to consider, Steady State theory--Hoyle Gold and Bondi--not taken seriously now, and, of course various religious creation myths taken seriously by some :)

Comment: Nice [rap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapping])!